# add custom attribute to wordpress navigation

Tags: php, wordpress

in wordpress admin panel when i create a nav menu , i can set title and class for each `<a>` in html structure .
in wordpress codex we can add setting for `<ul>`  like below :

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

the problem is how i can add some attribute  like `data-hover` in my nav generator of wordpress ? any body can help how can add custom attribute to each `<a>` of nav menu .

Comment: Not a WordPress guy, but have you tried adding one more key to array for data attribute?

Comment: no ... but if i add a data attr key ... how desplay it in admin panel to show for users ? 
user must can change data attr of any <li> in admin panel

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom walker for the menu. Please see here for an example: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function